# Gong Drag and Drop between two of the same applications

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop between two instances of the same application using the GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop.

When I drop on top of the second application I get an error that says

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
Invalid tymed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040069 (DV_E_TYMED))
```

The dataformat that I get returned from the object is "GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't the solution to your problem, but I had a problem with GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop and I could resolve it by directly getting in touch with the developer:

- Create a minimal demo that causes your problem and ZIP that
- Go to the project GitHub page (https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop)
- Create an issue and attach your demo

That way punker76 can most easily find and resolve the issue and/or help you with your problem.